# Where is the session token stored on the client on cookieless session?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, cookieless

We have a situation when cookieless session is established. In order to tell the server who we are we have to send request with URL consisting of session token.
Where is it stored on the client? In the hidden field? Is it just taken from an URL in a browser from previous response? What if it is deleted by the user?

Comment: The token is present only in the url. If it's deleted/altered, the client hits a new/empty session.

Comment: your comment answers my question. thank you Wiktor